# The requested URL was not found when calling an ajax function

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

//I want to insert a text in the database (MySql) by calling a js function then another js //scripts retrieves the data from the database and displays it in a div on my html page //from //where i posted the text ....

//HTML from where i submit the text to be saved in the database

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "change">Naruto</div>
<form id = "foo" action = "update()">
<input type = "text" name = "text" id = "text"/>
<input type = "submit" value = "change" ></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

// the function that is called when i click the button

```
<script>

function update()
{
    $("#foo").submit(function(event) {

    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* Clear result div*/
    $("#result").html('');

    /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var values = $(this).serialize();

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
        url: "acition.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
            $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
            $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
    });
});
}
</script>
```

//the php file that actually updates the data

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("CANNOT CONNECT TO THE DATABASE".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ajax_database") or die ("CANNOT CONNECT TO THE DATABASE");

$text = $_POST['text'];
$sql = "insert into news(statement)values('$text')";
mysql_query($sql);
?>
<html>

<head></head>
<body>
```

// the script that gets the data from a different page to show it to the html div

```
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

// the php file that selects the data to be retrieved from the database 
// getdata.php

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("CANNOT CONNECT TO THE DATABASE".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ajax_database") or die ("CANNOT CONNECT TO THE DATABASE");
$sql = "select * from news";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $rows[0];
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

//basically just like we update the status on facebook .... i am doing the same thing .... //without refreshing the whole page it refreshes the part of the html page where the new //updated text will be shown 
//`enter code here`thanks i am really in a mess right now .... please help me out .... i am //new to ajax ...

Comment: Maybe "acition.php" should be "action.php" in update function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id = "foo">
  <input type = "text" name = "text" id = "text"/>
  <input type = "submit" value = "change" ></input>
</form>
```

remove action attribute and in javascript

```
$("#foo").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#result").html('');
    $.ajax({
        url: "action.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
            $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
            $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
    });
});
```

you don't need to call any function on submit, as u are already using jquery submit

Comment: the html and the java script are on the same page .... even if we ignore the other working of the pages .... it is not even adding the data in the database ..... it should atleast insert the data in the data base .... but its not